# How to build a backend to Whatsapp Bot to handle multiple users?

Tags: whatsapp, smooch

I want to know if it is possible to handle multiple users in Whatsapp using Smooch and how.

Right now, I have a free app in Smooch 14-day free trial tier and using Smooch sandbox integration mode.  This app is the frontend that the user would use to interact with the system.  I know that smooch sandbox has the limitation of only one user per sandbox and only one phone number per app.

I'm working on a system where it'd be expected to have multiple users in the system and interacting using Whatsapp as the medium.  As this is still a proof of concept, I'm going with the free tier.

I'm using AWS Lambda to provide the backend functionality for the app.  As it stands, I have to write multiple functions to different users.  The app credentials are hard coded.

If anyone has worked on a non-free tier in Smooch or production integration mode or has developed an app that'd cater to multiple users, please give me some insight on how you made it work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WhatsApp sandbox is limited to one user, but there other user-facing channels supported by Smooch that are not limited in this way, even on a Trial plan. [Facebook](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/facebook-messenger/) and the [Smooch Web Messenger](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/) are two good examples. There are [many others](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/channel-capabilities/).

You could use those channels to implement your multi-user lambda scenarios in order to prepare for the eventual deployment of a fully functional multi-user WhatsApp integration. The beauty of Smooch is that sending and receiving messages works mostly the same way for each of these channels.

Disclaimer: There are *some* WhatsApp specific capabilities such as [HSM](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/whatsapp/#how-to-start-conversations). Until you have a full WhatsApp integration provisioned, you would only be able to test HSMs using the WhatsApp Sandbox.

Comment: Thank you for your input Andrew.  When you mentioned 'full Whatsapp integration', did you mean 'Production' integration mode or 'Premium tier'?  Also with full integration, would you say its possible to interact with multiple people using a single app credentials?  I shall look into other channels as you suggested and tweak the code further down the line to focus on Whatsapp.

Comment: I’m not sure. ‘Production’ and ‘Premium’ might be referring to the same thing here. In contrast to the sandbox WhatsApp integration that’s only intended for testing, I was talking about a hosted WhatsApp client, described in detail here: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/whatsapp#whatsapp-api-client-hosting This is how your WhatsApp business number would run in production.